# weekly data from the mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

using below query for daily unique user, I need unique count for week how to use $week operator in this query to get unique weekly count, added the schema object collection below, how  to modify the query for  daily unique records count to  get weekly unique count records.

```
db.custom.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {Dates: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime"}}, Role: "$customROLE"},
            uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": NumberInt(0),
            "Dates": "$_id.Dates",
            "ROLE": "$_id.Role",
            "TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}
        }
    }
])
```

My current output:

```
[
    {
        "Dates" : "2020-05-11",
        "ROLE" : "CS_GMR",
        "TOTALUSERS" : 3
    },
    {
        "Dates" : "2020-05-11",
        "ROLE" : "PS_MGR",
        "TOTALUSERS" : 2
    },
    {
        "Dates" : "2020-05-11",
        "ROLE" : "SE_PECH",
        "TOTALUSERS" : 9
    },
    {
        "Dates" : "2020-05-11",
        "ROLE" : "NS_IS",
        "TOTALUSERS" : 130
    }
]
```

My Schema object like:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 55,
    "id" : "dm4955",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.lh.com",
    "Role" : "PS_MGR",
    "event" : "TIMEOUT",
    "timeoutTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:33:13.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T18:33:14.663Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : 38,
    "attUid" : "mo441b",
    "host" : "iefs-las.web.lh.com",
    "Role" : "CS_GMR",
    "event" : "LOGIN",
    "loginLogoutTime" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:34.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:41:35.220Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `$dateToString` to `$week` in your `$group` stage:

```
db.custom.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {week: {$week: "$loginLogoutTime"}, Role: "$customROLE"},
            uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"} ,
            Dates: {$addToSet: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime"}}}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "_id": NumberInt(0),
            "week": "$_id.week",
            "Dates": "$Dates",
            "ROLE": "$_id.Role",
            "TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: No, i just copied your pipeline - you can dump that stage.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to include the document schema and the expected output you want, it's currently not clear to me.

Comment: Using below query for daily unique user count:db.custom.aggregate([
    { $match: {   "loginLogoutTime": {
                "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),
                "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-11T14:32:00.000-0400")}} },
    {$group: { _id: {Dates: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date:"$loginLogoutTime"}}, Role: "$customROLE"}, uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"}
        }},
    {
 $project: {
            "_id": NumberInt(0),
            "Dates": "$_id.Dates",
            "ROLE": "$_id.Role",
            "TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}
        }
    }
])

Comment: can we put loginLogoutTime "$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"), "$lt": ISODate("2020-04-17T14:32:00.000-0400") .....10 to 17 for getting weekly data.

Comment: db.custom.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {"loginLogoutTime": {"$gte": ISODate("2020-04-10T14:30:00.000-0400"),"$lt": ISODate("2020-04-17T14:32:00.000-0400")}}},
    {$group: {_id: {week: {$week: "$loginLogoutTime"}, Role: "$customROLE"},uniqueCount: {$addToSet: "$id"} ,Dates: {$addToSet: {$dateToString: {format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$loginLogoutTime"}}}}},
    {$project: {"_id": NumberInt(0),"week": "$_id.week","Dates": "$Dates","ROLE": "$_id.Role","TOTALUSERS": {$size: "$uniqueCount"}}}])

Comment: Again do you mind adding the document schema ( how a random document in the collection looks like) and your expected out (exactly what output structure you expect) to your question? the current aggregation and current output you just gave me don't really help.

Comment: We have collection like: {
    "_id" : 55, "Uid" : "md4996","host" : "iefs-las.web.pt.com","agentRole" : "FS_SE_HECH","event" : "TIMEOUT",
    "timeoutTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T14:33:13.000Z"),
    "lastupdatedTimeStamp" : ISODate("2018-10-26T18:33:14.663Z"),
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0}

Comment: if needs only 5 days data from week how can i use above query